# element.val() returning previous value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, google-places-api

Here is my problem

I am trying to create a button that calls a directive function which then activates the google place 'place_changed' event that is assigned to the directive. If the getPlace() function doesn't return a result e.g. `var result = scope.gPlace.getPlace();` then I want force a place prediction by doing the following.

```
if( result === undefined ) {
   result = { name: element.val() }
}
```

however the problem is that this code will work when the page is first loaded but subsequent attempts will assign the var `result` to the previous text that was entered. e.g. Type "Adelaide" and click on the button equals successful process however now type melbourne and click on the button will still equal "Adelaide"

```js
'use strict';
angular.module( "ngAutocomplete", [])
  .directive('ngAutocomplete', function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: {
        ngModel: '=',
        options: '=?',
        details: '=?',
        setFn: '&'
      },

      link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {

        //options for autocomplete
        var opts
        var watchEnter = false
        //convert options provided to opts
        var initOpts = function() {

          opts = {}
          if (scope.options) {

            if (scope.options.watchEnter !== true) {
              watchEnter = false
            } else {
              watchEnter = true
            }

            if (scope.options.types) {
              opts.types = []
              opts.types.push(scope.options.types)
              scope.gPlace.setTypes(opts.types)
            } else {
              scope.gPlace.setTypes([])
            }

            if (scope.options.bounds) {
              opts.bounds = scope.options.bounds
              scope.gPlace.setBounds(opts.bounds)
            } else {
              scope.gPlace.setBounds(null)
            }

            if (scope.options.country) {
              opts.componentRestrictions = {
                country: scope.options.country
              }
              scope.gPlace.setComponentRestrictions(opts.componentRestrictions)
            } else {
              scope.gPlace.setComponentRestrictions(null)
            }
          }
        }

        if (scope.gPlace == undefined) {
          scope.gPlace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], {});
        }

        google.maps.event.addListener(scope.gPlace, 'place_changed', function() {

          var result = scope.gPlace.getPlace();

          //hack to make sure we have an object to pass to ensure we can get results from the called function activateGetPlace
          if( result === undefined ) {
            result = { name: element.val() }
          }

          console.log("the result", result);

          if (result !== undefined) {

            if (result.address_components !== undefined) {

              scope.$apply(function() {
                scope.details = result;
                controller.$setViewValue(element.val());
              });
            }
            else {
              if (watchEnter) {
                getPlace(result)
              }
            }
          }
        })

        //function to get retrieve the autocompletes first result using the AutocompleteService
        var getPlace = function(result) {
          var autocompleteService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
          if (result.name.length > 0){
            autocompleteService.getPlacePredictions(
              {
                input: result.name,
                offset: result.name.length,
                types: opts.types,
              componentRestrictions: opts.componentRestrictions
              },
              function listentoresult(list, status) {
                if(list == null || list.length == 0) {

                  scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope.details = null;
                  });

                } else {
                  var placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(element[0]);
                  placesService.getDetails(
                    {'reference': list[0].reference},
                    function detailsresult(detailsResult, placesServiceStatus) {

                      if (placesServiceStatus == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        scope.$apply(function() {

                          controller.$setViewValue(detailsResult.formatted_address);
                          element.val(detailsResult.formatted_address);

                          scope.details = detailsResult;

                          //on focusout the value reverts, need to set it again.
                          var watchFocusOut = element.on('focusout', function(event) {
                            element.val(detailsResult.formatted_address);
                            element.unbind('focusout')
                          })

                        });
                      }
                    }
                  );
                }
              });
          }
        }

        controller.$render = function () {
          var location = controller.$viewValue;
          element.val(location);
        };

        //watch options provided to directive
        scope.watchOptions = function () {
          return scope.options
        };

        scope.$watch(scope.watchOptions, function () {
          initOpts()
        }, true);

        scope.activateGetPlace = function() {
          google.maps.event.trigger(scope.gPlace, 'place_changed');
        }

        scope.setFn({theDirFn: scope.activateGetPlace});

      }
    };
  });
  
  var mechanicsearch = angular.module('mechanicsearch', ['ngRoute','ngResource','ngAutocomplete']),
    radiusOptions = [];

mechanicsearch.run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on('handleActiveJobsPanel', function(event, args) {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('activateJobsPanel', args);
  });
  $rootScope.$on('handleActiveFinalise', function(event, args) {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('activateFinalisePanel', args);
  });
  $rootScope.$on('handleActiveSearch', function(event, args) {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('activateSearchPanel', args);
  });
});

mechanicsearch.filter('htmlToPlaintext', function() {
  return function(text) {
    return  text ? String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '') : '';
  };
});

// mechFactory service
mechanicsearch.factory('mechFactory', function($resource,$window) {
    var mechanics = [];
    var jobs = [];

    var addMechanic = function(mechanic){
      mechanics.push(mechanic);
    };

    var getAllMechanics = function(){
      return mechanics;
    };

    var removeAllMechanics = function() {
      mechanics = [];
    }

    var addJob = function(job) {
      jobs.push(job);
    }

    var getAllJobs = function() {
      return jobs;
    }

    var removeAllJobs = function() {
      jobs = [];
    }

    return {
      getMechanics: function(location,radius) {
        return $resource('/ajax/api.cfm?api=mechanic&function=getMechanicByLocation&lat=:lat&lng=:lng&radius=:radius' ).get({lat:location.lat,lng:location.lng,radius:radius});
      },
      getJobs: function() {
        return $resource('/ajax/api.cfm?api=job&function=getJobsAssignedtoWorkshop' ).get();
      },
      sendMechanicsJobNotifications: function(mechanics, jobs) {
        return $resource('/ajax/api.cfm?api=job&function=sendMechanicsJobNotifications&mechanics=:mechanics&jobs=:jobs' ).get({mechanics:mechanics.toString(),jobs:jobs.toString()});
      },
      addMechanic: addMechanic,
      removeAllMechanics: removeAllMechanics,
      getAllMechanics: getAllMechanics,
      addJob: addJob,
      removeAllJobs: removeAllJobs,
      getAllJobs: getAllJobs
    }
});


mechanicsearch.controller('SearchCtrl', ['$timeout', '$scope', '$window', '$location', '$routeParams', 'filterFilter', 'mechFactory', '$resource', '$element',

    function ($timeout, $scope, $window, $location, $routeParams, filterFilter, mechFactory, $resource, $element) {

        $scope.place = {};
        $scope.place.address = null;
        $scope.place.lat = null;
        $scope.place.lng = null;
        $scope.radius = 25;
        $scope.mechanics = [];
        $scope.selection = [];
        $scope.alert = null;
        $scope.showSearchPanel = true;

        //Helper method to get selected mechanics
        $scope.selectedMechanics = function selectedMechanics() {
          filterFilter($scope.mechanics, { selected: true })
        };

        //allow mechanic checkbox to select/deselect on click
        $scope.toggleMechanicSelect = function(mechanic) {
          mechanic.selected = !mechanic.selected;
        }

        $scope.goToJobListing = function() {
          $scope.showSearchPanel = false;
          mechFactory.removeAllMechanics();
          for( var i in $scope.selection ) {
            mechFactory.addMechanic($scope.selection[i]);
          }
          $scope.$emit('handleActiveJobsPanel');
        }

        // watch mechanics for changes
        $scope.$watch('mechanics|filter:{selected:true}', function (nv) {
         $scope.selection = nv.map(function (mechanic) {
           return mechanic.objectid;
         });
        }, true);

        //watch the returning google autocomplete details object
        $scope.$watch('details', function() {
          if( $scope.details !== undefined && $scope.details !== null ) {
            $scope.place.address = $scope.details.formatted_address;
            $scope.place.lat = $scope.details.geometry.location.lat();
            $scope.place.lng = $scope.details.geometry.location.lng();
          }
        });

        // watch the $scope.place data for changes
        $scope.$watchCollection('place', function() {
          if( $scope.place.lat !== null || $scope.place.lng !== null ) {
            $scope.getMechanics();
          }
        });

        $scope.$watch('radius', function() {
          if( Number.isInteger(parseInt($scope.radius))  ){
            $scope.getMechanics();
          }
        });

        $scope.setDirectiveFn = function(directiveFn) {
          $scope.directiveFn = directiveFn;
        };

        $scope.getMechanics = function() {
          mechFactory.getMechanics($scope.place, $scope.radius).$promise.then(
            function successfulResult (mechanicsData) {

              if (!mechanicsData || !mechanicsData.data.length){
                $scope.alert = 'Sorry, no mechanic found in "' + $scope.place.address + '" with radius of ' + $scope.radius + '.';
                $scope.mechanics = [];
                $scope.selection = [];
              } else {
                $scope.alert = mechanicsData.data.length + ' mechanic(s) found in "' + $scope.place.address + '" with radius of ' + $scope.radius + ' km.';
                $scope.mechanics = mechanicsData.data;
                $scope.selection = [];
              }

            }, function failedResult (err) {
              $scope.alert = err.message;
            });
        };

        //display panel once we have recieved the event
        $scope.$on('activateSearchPanel', function(event, args) {
          $scope.mechanics = [];
          $scope.selection = [];
          $scope.alert = null;
          $scope.showSearchPanel = true;
          $scope.place = {};
          $scope.radius = 25;
        });
    }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCmN0htBqG3DGo04KKKzC9srgIrhP0Dq5o&libraries=places"></script>
  
  
<div id="mechanicsearch" data-ng-app="mechanicsearch">

        <div data-ng-controller="SearchCtrl" ng-show="showSearchPanel">
          <aside class="workshopsearch" >

              <form method="post" class="form-inline" role="form">
                <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-6 form-group input-group-lg">
                          <input type="text" id="geoSearch" ng-model="autocomplete" class="form-control" ng-autocomplete options="{ types: 'geocode', country: 'au', watchEnter: true }" details="details" set-fn="setDirectiveFn(theDirFn)" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-6 input-group input-group-lg">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="radius" id="radius" placeholder="Radius" data-ng-model="radius">
                        <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-go" ng-click="directiveFn()">Go</button</span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </form>
          </aside>
         </div>
        </div>
```

}

Comment: Why are you using `element.val()` when you have an `ngModel` bound to the input? Why not use `scope.ngModel` instead?

Comment: Because I clearly do not know much about how angular works haha. Thank you!!! this works, if you post this as an answer ill mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: Done. If you're using jQuery to get values, you need to wrap the calls in `scope.$apply()` to make the changes known to Angular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using `element.val()` when you have an `ngModel` bound to the input? Why not use `scope.ngModel` instead?